# c# fixed tcp client local endpoint port causes SocketException

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, endpoint

Can i unbind socket from local endpoint? For security purposes, i need to fix source port for TCP communication. In this client code i fix source port to `42448`:

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, 
ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.123"), 42448);
s.Bind(localEP);
s.Connect(remoteEP);
s.Send(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 });
s.Close();
```

It works only once. Second time it throws `SocketException` (that address already in use) on the `s.Connect` line as i see in `netstat`, there is one connection from this source port `42448` with `TIME_WAIT` state, even if i close the app. after about 1 minute this `TIME_WAIT` connection disappears and i can run my code, but again just once. how can i properly unbind this socket so i can run code many times?

**Update 1**
it is not a server socket, so there is no listening here. `LingerOption` is also doesnt work:

```
LingerOption lo = new LingerOption(false, 0);
s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, lo);
```

Comment: There are many questions asking about the same stuff. Question I've decided to put as a duplicate example was just the first one I've got from the search results: [How to unbind socket in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821520/how-can-i-unbind-a-socket-in-c)

Comment: @m.rogalski i think its a different question, i added an Update